# Trying to import an installed wheel file

Tags: python, python-wheel

I have a wheel file , which I have created and installed in my laptop . The problem is , after installing it , I am unable to import it .

For some references , here is setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="vk01",
version=0.1,
description="This package will help to edit a particular line in Python .",
author="Vishal",
packages=find_packages("VK_001", exclude=['test']),
install_requires=[])
```

And the name of the wheel file is vk01-0.1-py3-none-any.whl .

Please help me regarding this matter . If required , I can tell you more about it ; you just have to ask it .

Edit-1 : To clarify more , here is one picture of me installing the wheel file and then importing it :-

[image]

Edit-2 : Here is the structure of my file :

`C:\Users\Name\PyCharmProjects\VK01\Packages\Module1\VK_001`

@ Here , in "VK01" , there are many python files and folders , including venv . But , all my stuff related to my package lies in "Packages" .

@ In "Packages" , there is only one folder , "Module1" .

@ In "Module1" lies "VK_001" , "readme.txt" and "license.txt". The txt files are not yet connected with the package .

@ In "VK_001" lies `__init__.py` and `setup.py` .

Comment: Did you install the wheel in the venv?

Comment: Yes and no . Are there any consequences ?